# Java - delete some files from File[] array

Tags: java, arrays

I have array File[] polFiles. Some files can be deleted by another function and I write function to clean remote files from an array. For example, if there was P0, P1, P2, P3, P4 in File [] polFiles, and were deleted by P1 and P2, now polFiles shall consist of P0, P2 and P4. How to make it? I wrote simple code but it throws any way exceptions and errors.

```
int delcount = 0;
for (File file : files) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        delcount++;
    }
}
File[] newfiles = new File[files.length-delcount];
int fcount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < newfiles.length; i++) {
    if (!files[i].exists()) {
        fcount++;
        for (int j = i; j < files.length-fcount-1; j++) {
            newfiles[j] = files[j+fcount];
        }
    } else {
        newfiles[i] = files[i+fcount];
    }
}
System.arraycopy(newfiles, 0, files, 0, newfiles.length);
for (int i = newfiles.length; i < files.length; i++) {
    files[i] = null;
}
```

Where is a mistake? This code throws Null exception and don't correctly work. It deletes only first file from array

Comment: Any reason why you are using an array rather than a `List`?

Comment: If you must use arrays, you will need to add the undeleted files to the new array and then shrink it (into a third array)...

Comment: @RealSkeptic file array is using by another program

Comment: And you can't assign it a new array? As it is, you merely have an array with nulls in the end, and any program that doesn't check for nulls will get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic `NullPointException` isn't important for me, correctly working more important than exception

Comment: Then you'll have to define a lot more clearly what it would mean that it's "working", as opposed to "not working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this without the help of libraries, then, try something like the following:

```
private File[] compactor(File[] files) {
    int deleted = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        File file = files[i];
        if (file.exists()) {
            files[i - deleted] = file;
        } else {
            files[i] = null;
            deleted++;
        }
    }

    int nSize = files.length - deleted;
    File[] newFiles = new File[nSize];
    if (nSize > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(files, 0, newFiles, 0, newFiles.length);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newFiles));
    return newFiles;
}
```

Just check if any boundary conditions needs to be added.

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier to work with `List`s than with arrays. Unless you have a good reason, let go of the array ... With some help of [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html#filter(com.google.common.base.Predicate)) this becomes much easier :

```
FluentIterable.from(files)
    .filter(new Predicate<File>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(@Nullable File file) {
            return file.exists();
        }
    }).toList();
```